# Get child of an object stored in Firebase using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection of simple Java objects (device tokens from an Android device) stored as documents in Firebase:

```
public class DeviceToken {
    String tokenID;


    public DeviceToken() {
    }

    public DeviceToken(String tokenID) {
        this.tokenID = tokenID;
    }


    public String getTokenID() {
        return tokenID;
    }

    public void setTokenID(String tokenID) {
        this.tokenID = tokenID;
    }
}
```

I[image]

I am attempting to get the `tokenID` child of this object as a string in javascript for the following cloud function:

```
exports.sendDMNotification = functions.firestore.document('/dm_threads/{thread_id}/messages/{message_id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


        const newMessage = snapshot.data();

        const senderName = newMessage.authorName;
        const senderID = newMessage.authorUID;
        const messageText = newMessage.message;
        const recipientName = newMessage.recipientName;
        const recipientID = newMessage.recipientUID;
        const timestamp = newMessage.timestamp;


        let deviceTokenQuery = admin.firestore().collection(`/users/${recipientID}/device_tokens/`);

        return deviceTokenQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {

            let tokenShapshot = querySnapshot.docs;

            const notificationPromises = tokenShapshot.map(token => {


                let token_id = token['tokenID'];

                console.log(token_id);
                console.log(token)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(token));


                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: senderName,
                        body: messageText,
                        icon: "default"
                    }
                };


                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)

            });

            return Promise.all(notificationPromises);

        });

    });
```

The first log statement returns undefined, the second returns [object Object] and the third returns what a appears to be a bunch of meta data the document reference, but none of the properties of the object as I'm using it. How do I just retrieve that `tokenID` child of the object documents I'm fetching?

Comment: If im not mistaken is is not `tokenShapshot.map(token => ({ ... })` ecapsulation ()? Also.. ` but none of the properties of the object as I'm using it` Can you tell us what the attributes are ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're callign `map` on the `querySnapshot.docs`, I assume each item passed to the `map` callback is a document. In that case, you still need to call `data()` to get the to data of the documents:

```
let tokenShapshot = querySnapshot.docs;

const notificationPromises = tokenShapshot.map(doc => {

    let token_id = doc.data().tokenID;
```

Comment: That method was what I needed. Thank you again.